# Whats the Point of Astrid's Map?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Whats the point of Astrid's Map in the Falkreath Dark Brotherhood sanctuary?

There are other maps that follow the progress of the civil war through flags, but all Astrid's does is randomly get daggers stabbed into it. Is there anything method to her map stabby madness?

Comment: Do the daggers indicate the location of targets?

Comment: No, not unless Astrid has her own unknown targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is nothing special about the dagger(s) stabbed in the map, they have no importance.

Comment: Purely speculation or do you known for a fact?

Answer (score 5):

From what I can gather they're the Dragonborn's contracts, starting with the little boy who has you kill the orphanage lady. It also seems to count for kills too, so it's just poorly thrown together and means very little.